# ¿Como puedo Iniciar una tarea Asíncrona cuando la anterior Tarea Asíncrona haya terminado?

Tags: c#, sql, .net

Les comparto unas imágenes.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Imagen 1. Es la lista de tareas.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Imagen 2. MEtodo asíncrono.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Imagen 3. Llamado de datos.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y de paso ganes tu primera medalla, también es muy importante que leas [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad. Adicional no coloques capturas de tu código, mejor copia y pegalo como texto.

Comment: Aqui no vayas a durar mucho con ese comportamiento mi chavo, debes leer las normas y aprender usar el sitio.

Comment: comportamiento? hice algo malo? no pude recuperar mi otra cuenta donde hice varias publicaciones. Por eso me cree esta.

Comment: Si tienes problemas con tus cuentas, ponte en contacto con algunos de los administradores. Ellos pueden ayudar o explicarte sobre el asunto de tu cuenta. Este era tu [usuario anterior](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/107638). Si es asi, como ya te comente. Ponte en contacto con los administradores, quizas ellos puedan unir las dos cuentas(no estoy seguro) o darte a elegir una de las dos.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Por favor, no uses imágenes salvo que sea absolutamente necesario. Mira por favor [aca](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976/324). Los errores y tu codigo deben ir como texto, siempre.

Comment: Aparte del tema de las imagenes. Sobre que cuenta perdiste el acceso? como lo perdiste? podrias poner una publicacion en [meta] respecto a tu problema para que podamos pedir que te devuelvan el acceso a tu vieja cuenta, o fusionen las mismas?

Comment: Muchas Gracias. Ya pude solucionar los de mi código. Y si, me gustaría que lo unan esta con mi cuenta anterior. Muchas gracias  a todos por su respuestas.

Answer (score 1):

Lo único que tienes que hacer es usar el await fuera de la función `GetConfigurationgeoBuildings()`, `GetConfigurationGeoFields`, etc...

Podes hacerlo de esta manera:

```
var a = await this.GetConfigurationGeoBuildings(....);
DownloadFieldList.Add(a);
```

Recuerda que las funciones asincronicas hay que usar el async/await en todo el stack de llamado de funciones.